# FTP file upload through Dreamweaver

Tags: permissions

Trying to edit files over FTP in Adobe Dreamweaver 2019. I've set the permissions to 755 in /var/www/html/ using -Rfv. Now, whenever I go to save a file I am greeted with this:

`An FTP error occurred - cannot put admin.html.  Access denied.  The file may not exist, or there could be a permission problem.   Make sure you have proper authorization on the server and the server is properly configured.`

Is this as simple as a permissions problem or have I messed something up big?

Comment: I guess the owner of `/var/www/html/` is root? (Use `ls -l /var/www/` to find out.) If so you have to bee root to have write permission.

Comment: Would I then have to `chown` it as `pi` (the account that I am trying to access with)?

Comment: Yes. Or change the permissions to 766 (which means that the owner gets all permissions, the group and all others get read and write permissions).

Comment: I hope you know what you are doing. Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777/20110#20110